# Laravel updating multiple records

Tags: php, laravel

I want an help, I need to update multiple rows using row id.

```
$sortable=$request->sortable;
    foreach ($sortable as $key => $id) {
        Category::where('id','=',$id)->update(['sort_order' => $key+1]);
    }
```

I find this method not feasible because it updates multiple times.
I want to do the same thing in only one update.

value in sortable is:
0:"2"
1:"1"
2:"4"
3:"3"
4:"5"

Comment: You can't update single column multiple times in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it's no possible to do it in one query because you assign unique value 'sort_order' to a specific id. You can do it one query only if all rows with given ids should get the same 'sort_order' value. However, you can improve your query with starting using transaction. It will bring two benefits:

1. Your data in table will be consistent. Update all or none.
2. Indexes if you use them on field 'sort_order' in your table  will be flushed once at the end of the transaction.

Laravel code that demonstrates the solution is below:

```
\DB::transaction(function () use ($sortable) {
    foreach ($sortable as $key => $id) {
        Category::where('id','=',$id)->update(['sort_order' => $key+1]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that use are using for each loop to update each row of your category hence this will be slow. Instead what you could do is that you could use a laravel eloquent method whereIn.

```
Category::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['sort_order' => 'do whatever you feel like updating']);
```

make sure $ids is an array of your ids.

Comment: This will work only if the `sort_order` value is identical for all rows (ids)